# jquery ajax open file in browser

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I have the following code that allows me to download a file and save it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: file['url'],
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = file['label'];
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
});
```

If the file is a PDF or text I would like to open it in the browser rather than save it. Is it possible? i know how to detect the type (PDF, text) but I do not know how to force the browser to open the file in a net tab or window. I am using Chrome.

Thank you

Comment: are you able to download file with ajax?

Comment: Yes, I can download the file